# SSHFS in fstab: Is there logging?

Tags: ssh, sshfs, fuse

I have configured a sshfs-mount in my fstab (with key-auth).

```
sshfs#sam@192.168.22.100:/  /mnt  fuse  defaults,allow_other,reconnect,_netdev  0 0
```

Works well as expected.

Last thing I need is a log on the client-side (I have no access to the server). I like to see if the connection is established and when it needs to reconnect.

I do not see anything in /var/log about it.

Answer (score 1):

On the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSHFS#fstab_mounting_issues) there is a solution, I just tested it, you just need to add this with the other fstab options and you will get plenty of logging when doing the mount:

`ssh_command=ssh\040-vv,sshfs_debug,debug`